# Expectation and asymptotic equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

This is a simplified version of the original question asked, it seems that some parts are unnecessary and only confuse. I will therefore here ask a related, but I believe simpler, version of the question. Let $0 < \lambda < 1$ and let $$S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$$ be a random walk with i.i.d. increments $X_i$ with law $P(X_1 =0) = P(X_1 =1 ) = 1/2$. Now, consider $$ E \left( \frac{\lambda^{S_n}} {\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda^{S_k}} \right).$$ The task is to find a sequence $f(n)$ (possibly random) such that
$$ E \left( \frac{\lambda^{S_n}} {\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda^{S_k}} \right) \Big/ {f(n)} \to 1 $$
and thus, find the growth behavior of the expectation at question.
Note that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda^{S_k} \to L:= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{S_k}$ a.s.

---

---

Here the question from before (first part deleted):

[...] Then, I am interested in general, what is the asymptotic growth behavior of $$ E \left( \frac{\lambda^{S_n} (1- \lambda^{S_n})}{\lambda^{S_n} + \sum_{k=0}^n \lambda^{S_k}} \right) ?$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\sim$? I'm asking because your r.h.s. is equivalent to $\lambda^{n/2}$.

Comment: @zhoraster By $\sim$ I mean asymptotic equivalence, i.e. $a_n \sim b_n$, if $a_n / b_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. And yes, I think you are correct. Therefore, I put the second edit in there, because I do not really think anymore that the expectation of that whole thing is equivalent to $\lambda^{n/2}$ (could be, but I am not sure about that).

Comment: Should be $(1-\lambda^{1/2})\cdot \lambda^{n/2}$. Anyway the claim is probably false.

Comment: Is lambda  also meant to be greater than 0? Or at least -1?

Comment: @Robo300 Yes, $0 < \lambda < 1$.